# Approaches for position-based animation using TextBlocks and Canvas controls

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, wpf-controls

I'm writing an app that simulates a news ticker. I chose WPF for its animation support, which is very nice, but I'm running into some questions about positioning.

I'm starting out with moving a TextBlock on a Canvas from the right edge of the screen to the left edge. I'm using a Storyboard tied to the `Canvas.Left` property of the `TextBlock`, and a `DoubleAnimation`.

How do I determine the correct values of the **From** and **To** values of the `DoubleAnimation` such that the text starts with its left edge at the right edge of the form and ends with its right edge at the left edge of the form? Do I need to use `Measure()` and the `ActualWidth` properties to determine this? Perhaps there's some other class I should use for the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextBlock.ActualWidth` property is available when the `TextBlock.Loaded` event is fired. The value of the `DoubleAnimation.To` property can then be `0 - textBlock.ActualWidth`. Now to find out the unit for Canvas positioning...